# angularjs ui-calendar Cannot read property 'calendars' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ui-calendar

I followed the instruction here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/ to create calendar in angularjs. However, when I tried `uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('render');` it cause an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendars' of undefined`.

I did add `ui-calendar` as dependency in my controller and `uiCalendarConfig` in my function's parameter. 
A
ll latest version of the javascript:

```
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" class="span8 calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>
```

Anyone figure out what I missed that causes the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a known issue in angular ui-calendar

please check the issue and it's solution [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/296)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, I need to use  `uiCalendarConfig.calendars.calendar.fullCalendar('render');` instead of `uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('render');`